# Powershell results different based on save location

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to extract all users from an OU who have not signed into their account in 365 number of days.

```
import-module activedirectory
get-aduser -SearchBase 'ou=staff,ou=brummitt,dc=DUNELAND,dc=LOCAL' -filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties samaccountname,lastlogondate |
    Where-object {$_.lastlogondate -lt (get-date).AddDays(-365)} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname >>'C:\stale\brummitt.txt'
```

In attempt to organize the folder these are stored in I have created a folder in my servers `C:` drive called stale and have a folder called scripts in which the powershell scripts are stored.

When I run the script with powershell and the save extension is `C:\stale\brummitt.txt` it outputs all users in that OU. When the save location is `C:\brummitt.txt` it returns the correct users who have not signed in for over a year. Why would the results be changing based on the save location and how can this be combated?

**Added:**
I am running the powershell script from within the scripts folder.

Comment: `>>` appends to a file, `>` overwrites it. Verify that your script has write access to both locations and that you're not misreading things. You can also go through a variable first (`$o = Get-AdUser ...; $o >> file.txt`) to ensure the target location can't possibly be the problem (which it should not be).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Tee-Object as a part of the pipeline?, that will give you the opotunity to check the stream to the file on console,